# Can AutoMapper map static properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, automapper

Given the two classes below, can I map the ApplicationSettings to the AppSettings?

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Of ApplicationSettings, AppSettings)()
Mapper.Map(Of ApplicationSettings, AppSettings)(ApplicationSetting.Load)

Public Class ApplicationSettings

    Public Property RecaptchaPrivateKey As String
    Public Property RecaptchaPublicKey As String

End Class

Public Class AppSettings

    Public Shared Property RecaptchaPrivateKey As String
    Public Shared Property RecaptchaPublicKey As String

End Class
```

Comment: Why have two classes here? Static methods on the source class to load, then static properties on the second. What does the second class provide that static properties on the first don't?

Comment: @Jimmy - The source class does not have static properties. I use XmlSerializer to serialize/deserialize some application level settings that I want to use through out the application, and I could use Application state, but it is not strongly typed, so I though this would be a perfect place for AutoMapper to do it's thing. Anyway's it seems as though it will not map the ApplicationSettings classes properties to the static properties of AppSettings.

Comment: You should be able to change AppSettings into a singleton and then Map ApplicationSettings To AppSettings.Instance.. I won't be able to give you code for it as I don't really know VB.NET syntax :)

Comment: @Can - Can you show me the C# for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sam asked for this in C#, here it goes:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string RecaptchaPrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string RecaptchaPublicKey { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationSettings
{
    private static ApplicationSettings _instance;

    public static ApplicationSettings Instance
    {
        get {
            if (_instance == null) { _instance = new ApplicationSettings();}                
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public string RecaptchaPrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string RecaptchaPublicKey { get; set; }

    private ApplicationSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

and to use this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationSettings, AppSettings>();
var appSettings = Mapper.Map<ApplicationSettings, AppSettings>ApplicationSettings.Instance);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posed, it proposes a change to the codebase to work around the problem (creating a singleton). It solves this person's specific problem, but it doesn't answer the more general question about whether AutoMapper can handle static properties.